# zyDE 11.14.1: Iterating over a dictionary example

Tags: python

Completely lost on how to do the second ask in this question:

1. Print the name and grade percentage of the student with the highest total of points.
2. Find the average score of each assignment.
3. Find and apply a curve to each student's total score, such that the best student has 100% of the total points.

Starting Code:

```
# student_grades contains scores (out of 100) for 5 assignments
student_grades = {
    'Andrew': [56, 79, 90, 22, 50],
    'Nisreen': [88, 62, 68, 75, 78],
    'Alan': [95, 88, 92, 85, 85],
    'Chang': [76, 88, 85, 82, 90],
    'Tricia': [99, 92, 95, 89, 99]
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour]. Stack Overflow is for specific questions, but there's no question here, and the help you're looking for is not very specific. Check out [How to ask and answer homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). See also [ask]. You could try breaking the problems down into smaller chunks, but if you're still lost, it might be more constructive to talk to your teacher or otherwise learn more before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
student_grades = {
    'Andrew': [56, 79, 90, 22, 50],
    'Nisreen': [88, 62, 68, 75, 78],
    'Alan': [95, 88, 92, 85, 85],
    'Chang': [76, 88, 85, 82, 90],
    'Tricia': [99, 92, 95, 89, 99]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(student_grades)
df['average score'] = df.mean(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Andrew  Nisreen  Alan  Chang  Tricia  average score
0      56       88    95     76      99           82.8
1      79       62    88     88      92           81.8
2      90       68    92     85      95           86.0
3      22       75    85     82      89           70.6
4      50       78    85     90      99           80.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with pure python

```
print([sum(assignment) / len(assignment) for assignment in zip(*student_grades.values())])
```

Basically we are trying to do what I outline in this picture - group the scores vertically so that we can find the average. Whenever you want to group across many lists, the zip function comes in handy

[image: group]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

student_grades = {
    'Andrew': [56, 79, 90, 22, 50],
    'Nisreen': [88, 62, 68, 75, 78],
    'Alan': [95, 88, 92, 85, 85],
    'Chang': [76, 88, 85, 82, 90],
    'Tricia': [99, 92, 95, 89, 99]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(student_grades)

# Calculate the average score
df['Average Score'] = df.mean(axis=1)


df.plot()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
   Andrew  Nisreen  Alan  Chang  Tricia  Average Score
0      56       88    95     76      99           82.8
1      79       62    88     88      92           81.8
2      90       68    92     85      95           86.0
3      22       75    85     82      89           70.6
4      50       78    85     90      99           80.4
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Took me a bit to figure out the way to solve this without using imports or anything other than the keys(), values() and dict() methods as per the instructions. Part 1 and 3 of the question seem simple enough and there are a lot of ways to do that, but it was the average per assignment that took a minute.

Here's how I solved it:

```
# student_grades contains scores (out of 100) for 5 assignments
student_grades = {
    'Andrew': [56, 79, 90, 22, 50],
    'Nisreen': [88, 62, 68, 75, 78],
    'Alan': [95, 88, 92, 85, 85],
    'Chang': [76, 88, 85, 82, 90],
    'Tricia': [99, 92, 95, 89, 99]
}
#create empty dict for assignment avgs
grade_per_assgn_avg = {   
    }
#Print the name and grade percentage of the 
#student with the highest total of points.
highest_total_points = 0
name = ''
grade = 0.00
for key,grades in student_grades.items():
   total_points = sum([num for num in grades])
   if highest_total_points < total_points:
      highest_total_points = total_points
      name = key
      grade = (highest_total_points/len(grades))  
print ('Student: {}, Grade: {}%\n'.format(name, grade))

#print assignment averages that were added to
#a new dict
i=0
while i< len(grades):
    assgn_total=0
    for grades in student_grades.values():
        assgn_total += grades[i]
        grade_per_assgn_avg[i+1] = assgn_total/len(student_grades.keys())
    i += 1
print('Average Grade Per Assignment: \n',grade_per_assgn_avg,'\n')

#add curve using grade var calc highest points above
percent_diff = 100-grade
last_grade = 0
save_name = ''
print('With Curve:')
for student,grades in student_grades.items():
    total_per_st = sum(student_grades[student])
    if total_per_st > last_grade:
        save_name = student
        percentage = ((sum(student_grades[save_name]))/len(grades)) + percent_diff
        print(save_name, percentage, '%')
```

Output:

```
Student: Tricia, Grade: 94.8%

Average Grade Per Assignment: 
 {1: 82.8, 2: 81.8, 3: 86.0, 4: 70.6, 5: 80.4} 

With Curve:
Andrew 64.6 %
Nisreen 79.4 %
Alan 94.2 %
Chang 89.4 %
Tricia 100.0 %
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for contributing, but unfortunately, the post you're replying to is off-topic and might end up being deleted, taking your post along with it. This is a Q&A site but there's no question. To learn more, check out the [tour]. See also [answer], mostly the section "Answer well-asked questions". Also [How to ask and answer homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341).